# 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, admob

Trying to use adBanner Firebase & got this export error

```
Attempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.
```